# Why I can't execute command in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, command

I have the html-page where I want to realize online work of the pluging. For now, user must do  4 steps to obtain the report. And I want to create the button which will do these steps online. On of the step - Compute in TaskJuggler. I have the installed program on computer. And for computing I need to execute command: tj3 'file name'.

Plugin for Redmine and I use Ruby on Rails.

The code which I use

```
<h2><%= l(:redmine_taskjuggler)%></h2>
<%= l(:project)%> : <%= @project %> - <%= @project.identifier %>
<p>
<%= submit_tag "Compute in TJ", :type => 'button', :onclick => "javascript:tj3_com()" %>
</p>

<textarea id='placeForText' cols='70' rows='7' disabled></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function tj3_com(){

<% name = "#{@project.identifier.gsub(/-/,'_')}" + '-' + "#{@project.tj_version.to_s.gsub(/\./,'_')}" + '-' +'20140331_145001' + '.tjp' %>
<% outp = `tj3 /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp` %>
document.getElementById('placeForText').innerHTML=document.getElementById('some_doing').innerHTML

}
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="some_doing">
<%= outp %>
</script>
```

And it's not working. But if I use

```
<% outp = `ls -l /home/kitsune/` %>
```

It's all working.

But if I want to use

```
<% `ls -l /home/kitsune/ > check.txt` %>
```

It's not working, file "check.txt" is not created. But if I use all this commands (tj3, ls -l) in irb, it's all working.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anybody help me?!

Comment: did u try using system methods?

Comment: Yes. It returns "false".

Comment: And if I try to use 

    system('tj3 /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp > check.txt')  

the file not created

Comment: `ls -l /home/kitsune/ > check.txt 2> error.txt` to see what was the actual error while writing check.txt

Comment: error.txt not created. And this problem is solved. But problem with tj3 not solved.

Comment: try to use IO.popen(see the documentation for that) which helps to read the result.

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem! The problem was because I didn't add the gem TaskJuggler to Gemfile of Redmine. But now I have this error: /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp:0: Error: Cannot open file /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp: Permission denied -

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% `ls -l /home/kitsune/ > public/check.txt` %>
```

Comment: Yes, it work. But I still need to use `tj3 /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp`

Comment: in you command line type "which tj3", it will returns the path to tj3. replace tj3 with its whole path.

Comment: Using "which tj3" I obtain /usr/local/bin/tj3 

I use <% outp = `/usr/local/bin/tj3 /home/kitsune/proj/pred-0_0_1-20140331_145001.tjp` %>. And nothing